# Serializing/Deserializing Type object using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization

Given an object obj of some class A, doing typeof(obj) gives a System.Type object representing A

```
Type objsType = obj.GetType();
```

I want to serialize (using BinaryFormatter) the object objsType and persist on disk so another module running in another AppDomain can deserailse it into a Type object even though it has no reference to the assembly in which A is defined.

when I try to deserialze, I get an error saying the currently executing module could not find the assembly that defined A.

How do I fulfill my requirement without running into errors? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it should actually be Type objsType = obj.GetType().

Comment: You can edit your question to change the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that. Types in .Net are closely tied to their assemblies and you can't load a type without first loading its assembly.

Comment: But I am not actually trying to load the type itself. I am trying to load the RunTimeType object that has information about the class.

Comment: But that *is* the type. If you need some specific information about the type, can't you just save that?

Comment: What I mean is, I dont have class A with me when I deserialize the Type object. Deserializer expects the class to which the bytes should be reconstructed to. The class here is System.RunTimeType(), isnt it? I do not understand why it should ask for the definition of A itself.

Comment: There isn't some fixes set of bytes that would represent a class. For example, if there is some method in the class that you didn't execute yet, its code was never read from the assembly, so it isn't even in memory in any form. `Type` represents the class as a part of an assembly, you can't separate the two.